# What does this use of the echo shell command do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

I found `echo -n $'\e]0;Hello World\a'` in a shell script that's part of a code base I'm working on. What exactly does that do? It certainly doesn't echo anything visible.

Note, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.5.

Comment: In addition to the already provided answers, note that the syntax used by this command is not portable so I would recommend the equivalent but POSIX compliant `printf "\033]0;Hello World\07"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `-n` prevents echoing a new-line at the end.
- `$'` is a Bash command that causes backslash-escaped characters in the string to be replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard. [More info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script)
- `\e` = ESCape.
- `\e]0;` is a [command to set the window's title](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104018/set-dynamic-window-title-based-on-command-input), in this case to set it to "Hello World"

[More info on *nix Echo here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uecho.htm)

Comment: This isn't correct; `\e[0;` would set normal text mode, but `\e]0;` sets the window title. The difference between the ANSI Control Sequence Introducer (CSI, `\e[`) and the Operating System Command (OSC, `\e]`) is important but easy to miss.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Good eye, corrected. :)

Comment: You answer is still slightly incorrect. The final `\a` doesn't ring the bell in this particular case but is part of the escape sequence as an ending delimiter to the window's title.

Answer (score 3):

In XTerm (or anything that emulates it), it sets the window's title to "Hello World". `\e]` is the ASNI escape code for an "operating system command" (OSC), which essentially means it's up to the operating system to define what it means; in XTerm, `<OSC>0;text<bel>` is used to set the window title.

See [wikipedia](https://superuser.com/questions/844941/what-does-this-use-of-the-echo-shell-command-do), and [Edward Moy's XTerm sequence list](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) (search for the "Operating System Controls" section).

Answer (score 0):

`\e]0;` is not a valid ANSI code, to get "normal display" it has to be `\e[0m`.
As indicated by the text under Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007's link you may combine a number of them in the same sequence:

```
$ echo -en "\e[0;31;7m TEST \e[0m"  
 TEST $  _
```

*That `TEST` will be reverse red*
Note that -e is required for escape sequence parsing. -n makes echo **not** print a (CR+)LF at the end.

Better yet is using terminfo codes by use of the `tput` command - `man 5 terminfo` is technical but probably fairly complete.
Why tput? Because terminals are not always ANSI, terminfo attempts to "fix" that by providing a single interface to as many terminals as possible.

... so `echo "$(tput sgr0)"` - is the same as `echo -e "\e[0m"` - if you have an ANSI terminal.